# Generating *.WAR (64bits x 32bits)

Tags: java

Is there any difference generating a *.war file using a 64bits VM rather than 32bits?

I'm facing an issue after deploy an application using a new laptop I’ve bought recently - Windows 7 and AMD 64bits processor. I didn’t touch in any application source code, but when generating the *.war through the Eclipse/Galileo and then deploy it into the server I’ve got an “Permgen Space” exception in runtime whenever I’m trying to show any report - built in Jasper Report - on the server side, locally all of them and also the old *.war file generated through my old computer (32bits)1 are working fine.

Following some details regarding the boxes:

**Locally:**

- Java 1.6.0_18 (64 bits)
- Apache Tomcat/6.0.20

**Server side:**

- Java 1.6.0_07 (32 bits)
- Apache Tomcat/6.0.20

Here you can see the exception logged:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:295)
org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:170)
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:425)
br.com.innosoft.jzytho.framework.struts.action.AcessoAction.processActionPerform(AcessoAction.java:166)
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:174)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

Let me know if you need any further detail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 32bit/64bit is not the problem here. Especially when only the build environment is different.

Comment: Maybe you could paste the actual exception here, so people here have better chance to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally: No.

I use the exact same scripts to build wars for our applications in dev through production. All production server are now 64bit but have been in the past 32bit. Some dev boxes are 64bit, some 32bit but all use the same mechanism for packaging wars.

Permgen space is a memory issue related to available memory and class metadata which *is* affected by processor/os architecture.

here's a discussion of this: 
[Explaining java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space](http://www.freshblurbs.com/explaining-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space)

Short answer is add a jvm startup parameter -XX:PermSize=64m or --XX:PermSize=128m when starting up the jvm on the 32bit platform.

Comment: Hmmm... just looked at our startup code. We actually use a -XX:MaxPermSize=256m rather than -XX:PermSize=something. It's been quite a while since we had this problem, so I'd mostly forgotten about it.

Comment: Okay, thanks, but why the oldest version of the *.war is working on the same server?

Comment: I'd guess it has fewer classes in it and so didn't run up against the PermGen buffer limit. It's an area of memory reserved for metadata describing user classes. Fewer such classes = less PermGen spaced used. Newer wars having more such classes = more PermGen space required.

Comment: I'll add that I've run up against this error before, but we ran into it not because of architecture change but when the total number of classes packaged in the war increased to some point (since many of the classes were from external jars, I have no idea how many actual classes were involved).

Comment: Hmmmm, I've added all jars I found at lib folder to the classpath. I think that it should be the problem. I will review that and then let you know. Thanks!

Comment: It's working now, thanks SuperMagic. Support guys just increased XX:MaxPermSize to 128m. On my side, I removed all unnecessary jars from the application as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference if you generate the WAR file using a 64bits VM or a 32bits. The WAR is basically a ZIP file format. The file format does not change with the VM.

Comment: Yeah, but you can find bytecode inside it in this case...Why the oldest version of the *.war is working on the same server? Can you explain that?

Comment: Is there any difference in configuration between the two Tomcats? Are you running them in Eclipse or standalone?

Comment: Yes, there is. Same version but differente distributions. Locally, I'm running the Tomcat in Eclipse.

Comment: Have you a larger memory size allocated to the server in Eclipse, in the Arguments tab of your Server Launch Configuration and maybe you forgot about them? Or is Eclipse configured with higher memory in eclipse.ini?

Comment: Locally, I don't have any problem.

Comment: I have understood that, but maybe you have a lot more resources allocated to your app in local than you do on the server.

Comment: The problem is: there is *NO* issue when I'm generating the *.war file to the same application - same source code - through my old 32bit computer. Did you get it now?